# Show/Add Converted Amount in Quote Template

Tags: quote-template

Is there a way to add converted amount in Quote Template?

[image]

Comment: Based on what you're showing, the math works for both original and converted amount.

Comment: I mean, If we create a quote, it's only showing the currency selected for the Opportunity (ex: USD) but the converted amount with the parenthesis is not showing. Can we add that?

Comment: what is your Corporate Currency, Record Currency, user's personal currency?

Comment: Corporate Currency - Euro |
Record Currency - USD |
Personal Currency - AUD